# UART 0 PCLK not registered (pi 3)

Tags: pi-3b+, uart

I'm using a rpi 3 and so to use the UART 0 I had to disconnect the bluetooth from it:

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
dtoverlay=midi-uart0
```

in /boot/config.txt

It works great but now at boot I get the warning messages:

*UART0_pclk not registered*

*UART0_pclk alias not registered*

It's not an issue as every thing works fine but if I could remove it it would be great :)

Thanks!!